# How to record the current tab of the user without giving them the prompt to choose which screen they want to share

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I am new to extension development, and I am trying to create something like loom chrome extension which would record user screen. After researching I found out that **desktopCapture api** can be used to record the user screen, but using the **desktopCapture** prompt the user to choose which screen they want to share.

I installed loom chrome extension and there was an option to record just the current tab of the user, and when I click on it, it didn't ask for permissions or choice, it just record the current tab seamlessly. How is that happening? How can I record just the current tab without any prompts or permissions?

The official chrome extension mentions that **recording the user screen or tab without their permission is considered invasive and may violate user privacy. It's always a good idea to be transparent with users about what you're capturing and why** I am a little confused about it, loom didn't ask for any permission before recording the current tab. And how to record the current tab without any privacy issues?

Comment: Please use [chrome.tabCapture.capture](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/tabCapture/#method-capture);

Comment: @NorioYamamoto, Thank you for answering, and can you please explain a little more about the permissions question?

Comment: I found this: *Some permissions may not display warnings when paired with other permissions. For example, the "tabs" warning will not show if the extension also requests "<all_urls>".* - Maybe you're doing something else that negates the warning

Comment: @ZachJensz, I just installed the loom chrome extension on a new browser and I clicked on the extension icon and an overlay popup on the screen which gives the option to record the full desktop or the current tab. When I clicked on the current tab, it started the recording without asking for any permissions or warnings. I want to make a similar feature like that. I am a little confused why it didn't ask for any permissions and I am not sure where can I seek more advice on this topic?